# PHP rename() duplicates file instead of using new version

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

Our site has a .csv file sent over everyday which we user to import data from a different system. The import works correctly sometimes, but I'm running into a problem where the script is importing repeat data instead of using the new file.

The system will continue to import the old file until I login through SFTP to view the file, then it will grab the new file. It seems like the script is loading the old file into memory then not clearing it out.

for example:

- A file is uploaded on January 1st
- That file is imported correctly.
- On Jan 2nd the same file is imported again.
- On Jan 3rd the same file is imported again.
- On Jan 4th I view the file through SFTP.
- On Jan 4th the new file will be imported.

The system will continue to import the old version of the file until I login through SFTP.

My code for the import is below. Does anything here explain what might be happening?

```
function energyuportal_cron () {

    if (($handle = fopen($CFG->dirroot.'/'."report.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            if (energyuportal_check_data($data[1], $data[4])) {
            // This imports the data        
            energyuportal_manage_completions($data[1], $data[4], $data[5], $data[7]);
            }

        }
        fclose($handle);

        rename($CFG->dirroot.'/'.$CFG->energyuportal_filelocation.'/'."report.csv", 
                $CFG->dirroot.'/'.'/old/'."report".date("Y-m-d-H-ia").".csv");


    } else {
        // Error
    }

return true;
}
```

Comment: check for the completion status of the rename ! carp if failed. You could try to 'rename' in source folder, then copy  to dest and unlink in source after the copy succeeds.

Comment: is that correct? you fopen `$CFG->dirroot.'/'."report.csv"`, but you have to rename `$CFG->dirroot.'/'.$CFG->energyuportal_filelocation.'/'."report.csv"` and here `$CFG->dirroot.'/'.'/old/'."report".date("Y-m-d-H-ia").".csv"` you have double slashes like `//old/report<date>.csv`.

Comment: And I would like to recommend use single quotes instead of double ones, because double quotes force php-interpreter to evaluates the content, even if the string doesn't content evaluable expressions.

Comment: check the return value of rename(), log an error if it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log the result of stat() on the file before doing an fopen().  Also try adding clearstatcache().

If you were doing an include() I would look at the caching settings of any byte code compiler, but you are not.  Therefore I would start to question the hosting environment and fs layer.

http://php.net/stat

http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php